# horizontalAccuracy and desiredAccuracy in location,iphone

Tags: iphone

After `didUpdateToLocation`,my new location (CLLocation) is

> newLocation = [37.785834  -122.406417]

Then I am printing the `horizontalAccuracy` of newLocation  `desiredAccuracy` of locationManager (CLLocationManager) and they are

> horizontalAccuracy is 5.000000
>
> desiredAccuracy is 10.000000

My question is where these number come from....Are they changing if you move to another new location.

Moreover, right after I create and initialize CLLocationManager, its desiredAccuracy is -1.Again, is -1 a default value for CLLocationManager ?

Please advice me about these issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They depends on the CoreLocation property desiredAccuracy, these make them a function of the  location mechanism enabled. You can use three kind of mechanisms radio, wifi, gps. The more you ask for accuracy in the manager the more you get smaller accuracy values (if possible) and the more you comusume your battery. Usually even if you set to use accuracy for navigation the first locations you will get will have big accuracy value because gps signal need to check for satellite and it will takes time. The smaller accuracy value you get the closer you are to a position in the reality.
The log you get for the core loc manager is just the value of an enumeration for the accuracies values

[update]
Yes those values could change. For instance you are getting position using GPS, you go into a building. GPS doesn't work inside buildings, the accuracy values will change according to the new location mechanism, if it switches to wifi you should see something between 300m-30m.

Comment: thanks for your comment. By the way, I know we can set desiredAccuracy for location manager or we can use the value generated by location manager. Therefore, I am wondering should we set or should we use the second one.

Comment: Hi ttran, depends on your requirements. The default value is kCLLocationAccuracyBest which means that it will look for better accuracy always, if in your user scenario you do not need such accuracy is better to change it to preserve battery. If you didn't change the desired accuracy property you are using the default, I usually set that value to kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters but It depends on your user scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy will change based on many factors.  Cell site signal, GPS satalites availability and wi-fi access.  Negative numbers indicate the value is bad and should not be used.  You can set the desired accuracy in the code, however this is not guaranteed... I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help. Please also take a look about the comment above.